# Passing String array from Java to C++

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

so I have 
String resultNative[] in Java and char result[][] in C++, how can I pass array from java to c++ using JNI? 
I have tried the following code but error. thank you.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_GetTargetData_returnResult(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
int size = env->GetArrayLength(resultNative);

for (int i=0; i < size; ++i)
{
    jstring string = env->GetObjectArrayElement(resultNative, i);
    result[i] = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, i);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, resultNative);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
}
```

}

Comment: It might be useful if you would also post the actual error you get.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make a copy of what GetStringUtf returns before releasing it. Otherwise you store a pointer to a freed memory and perhaps access it later on. Using std:string is the right way to do it in c++, but you could use strdup if you really insist.

If result is an array of std:string, this is as simple as
    result[i] = std:string(env->GetStringUTFChars(string, i));

Comment: hmm. do you have an example of how to do this properly? maybe the way i'm doing this is wrong.. i'm new to this and not so familiar with C++ :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a parameter. Also, you're releasing the string before you even use it. Assigning it to `result[i]` just makes a shallow copy (copy of the pointer, not the contents). After releasing it, `result[i]` becomes invalid.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_GetTargetData_returnResult(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject stringArray)
{
    int length = env->GetArrayLength(stringArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        jstring jstr = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(stringArray, i);
        const char* cpp_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, 0);

        std::cout<<cpp_string<<"\n";

        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, cpp_string);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(jstr);
    }
}
```

OR if you want to save the string then:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_GetTargetData_returnResult(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject stringArray)
{
    int length = env->GetArrayLength(stringArray);

    std::vector<std::string> array_of_str(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        jstring jstr = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(stringArray, i);
        const char* cpp_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, 0);

        array_of_str.emplace_back(cpp_string);

        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, cpp_string);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(jstr);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, umm.. i think i'm wrong with the JNI syntax, can you please help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065390/get-java-array-from-c-via-jni