# Get java array from c++ via JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

So, I want to obtain resultNative from c++ 
but resultNative is in Java.
can anybody please show me how to do that via JNI? I am not so familiar with c++ and have searched google for a long time but didn't find any answer. thank you so much.
the nativeResult is here in Java.

```
public String[] searchDatabase()
{
    String result[]=new String[6];
    String nativeResult[]=new String[2];
    tName=this.getTargetName();

    result=da.SearchKorea(tName,ctx);
    tType=result[2];
    tTrans=result[3];
    tImage=result[4];
    tFave=result[5];

    nativeResult[1]= tImage+" - "+tName;
    nativeResult[2]= tTrans+" ["+tType+"]";
    return nativeResult;
}
```

Comment: You will have to do a call from C++. Create an instance of a JVM, find searchDatabase, and call it. This is the only way for C++ to CALL a java function. Otherwise, you'll need to call the C++ function from java and pass it the result of searchDatabase.

Comment: It is not clear from your text that you want to receive an array of `String`s from Java for use in C code; would you like to edit your question? Actually, there are two different scenarios: provide `String[]` parameter to a C function from Java, or use `searchDatabase()` method as a _callback_ from C code.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to get a reference to the class providing the method. Let's say your class is called MyClass and it is in package p. You get the reference to the class like this:

```
// You get the JNIEnv* pointer when calling a native function.
jclass myClass = env->FindClass("p/MyClass");
```

Or if you have a reference to the java object then you can also use `GetObjectClass`:

```
jclass myClass = env->GetObjectClass(javaObject);
```

Then you have to get the ID of the method you'd like to call by providing the name of the method and a string describing the signature of the method.

```
"()[java/lang/String;" describes a method expecting no arguments and returning a string array.
jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID(myClass , "searchDatabase", "()[java/lang/String;");
```

Then you have to call the method with `JNIEnv::CallObjectMethod`, and here you have to pass the referenc to the java object.

```
jobjectarray strings = env->CallObjectMethod(javaObject, methodID);
```

Then you can get an element of the array with `GetObjectArrayElement`.

```
int index = 0;
jstring string = env->GetObjectArrayElement(strings, index);
```

And then you can get the native string from it in various ways.

```
const char* nativeChars = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, nullptr);
```

You can find more information about JNI [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html), and details about JNI type signatures [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do it by passing back a jobjectArray.

```
int elements = 5;
jobjectArray returnArray = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(elements, env->FindClass("java/lang/string"), env->NewStringUTF(""));
for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
    char str[12];
    sprintf(str, "%i", i);
    env->SetObjectArrayElment(returnArray, i, env->NewStringUTF(str));
}

return returnArray;
```

I've only done this with a byte array

Comment: I mean, my c++ needs the nativeResult from java, how can I make a function in c++ to get the nativeResult from java?

Comment: Your JNI code would take in a jobjectArray as one of its parameters. You can use the env->GetObjectArrayElement to get a single jobject item. Cast it to a jString and convert it to a c string with env->GetStringUTFChars(env, STRING_VAR_HERE);